# Blockchain.info testnet websocket doesn't work

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain.info, api, testnet

When I try to connect testnet websocket provided by blockchain.info api. Connection doesn't establish, when i looked into the code. It says for testnet it uses "wss://ws.testnet.blockchain.info/inv" url. I guess that blockchain.info stops the service for testnet. Is there any other websocket api provider for bitcoin testnet?

Answer (score 0):

`~> curl --head https://testnet.blockchain.info
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable`

It's likely the service just isn't something that exists.

Comment: I found out another way to do this. smartbit.com.au provide api for both testnet and mainnet for bitcoin with some awesome api playground. I built my app over this website. But thanks for your comment though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the Esplora [API](https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora/blob/master/API.md) that powers [blockstream.info](https://blockstream.info/testnet/) for testnet blockchain data.

For example you can use curl to get the latest testnet block hash:

```
curl https://blockstream.info/testnet/api/blocks/tip/hash
```